# create random curve lines in an image for captcha

Tags: php, gd, captcha

I want to create an script for creating captcha images similar to the captcha used by some popular websites like in the image below.
I have created the script which generates captcha but I want to make it somewhat like below

[image]

And I want to add those random lines in the image but I cant figure our how can I achieve it,Please suggest how to do it in PHP.or any similar open-source project I can reference to.

Comment: Probably because you haven't supplied your code that you have written already.

Comment: Why reinventing the well when librairies can do it for you? http://www.thefreecountry.com/php/captcha.shtml

Comment: CAPTCHAs are of questionable utility, and they can render a site unusable to people with visual issues.

Comment: @fluminis-because none of those is like above and I want something like above and as an learner isnt it good to design it of my own.

Comment: can you copy some image and paste over your capcha image? like a png with a lot of line, ejample http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/9/4/4/11954244791861345463rejon_Noise.svg.hi.png

Comment: @kraysak-Yes but I want to achive this using coding is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below code gives you a starting point to do what you want. Note that this gives a much simpler output than the example images you posted.

Here are 4 generated images:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

The only part you are really are interested in is the `for` loop, but this is a fully working example:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 75);

$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 220, 220);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// set background colour.
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 75, $bg);

// output text.
imagettftext($im, 35, 0, 10, 55, $black, 'arial.ttf', 'ABCD');

for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    //imagefilledrectangle($im, $i + $i2, 5, $i + $i3, 70, $black);
    imagesetthickness($im, rand(1, 5));
    imagearc(
        $im,
        rand(1, 300), // x-coordinate of the center.
        rand(1, 300), // y-coordinate of the center.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc width.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc height.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc start angle, in degrees.
        rand(1, 300), // The arc end angle, in degrees.
        (rand(0, 1) ? $black : $white) // A color identifier.
    );
}

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Tweaking the limit of the `for` loop and the max value in the `rand()` calls will affect the 'density' of the arcs.