# Random line generation in an image in PHP

Tags: php, php-gd

Good day,

We are trying to generate these lines in an image in php.

[Image with random lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5VVw.jpg)

[image]

But we haven't close enough like this one.

Is there anything you can suggest to generate this kind of image via PHP?

Thank you.

PS. We used PHP GD library.

This is my code.

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);  
    imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,200,50,$background_color);
    $line_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 211,211,211); 
    for($i=0;$i<40;$i++) {
        imageline($image,0,rand()%50,200,rand()%50,$line_color);
    }

    imagepng($image, "image.png");
```

Comment: Always add your code to the question, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: First of all, you need to share your code, and secondly, are you trying to create a captcha?

Comment: I edited and shared my code my code, and yes. I'm trying to create a captcha

Comment: please vist this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860288/create-random-curve-lines-in-an-image-for-captcha